# What's the difference between "peeing on the streets" and "peeing in the streets"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

For instance, I know that "being on the street" means being somewhere on the streets, while "being in the street" means being in the streets where cars are being driven. However, I am not sure if the same thing can be said with the verb "pee". So is "peeing on the street" equivalent to "peeing anywhere on the street" and "peeing in the street" equivalent to "peeing in the middle of the street"?

Comment: No. There's still a distinction, but it's not the same one...

Comment: *Being on the street* and *peeing on the street* can both have multiple meanings. What would the contexts be in which the phrases are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "Peeing on the streets" describes the consequence of the action (urinating onto the surface of the street).
- "Peeing in the streets" (or, more commonly, "peeing in the street") describes the location of the action (standing in the street while urinating).  Note that the specific location (side, middle, right lane...) is not explicitly understood.  You can assume "the middle of the street," though, because the idiom can refer to any location on a street, not just the physical middle.

Comment: Is this like asking about the difference between crapping _in_ your pants, and crapping _on_ your pants?

Comment: Should you provide some examples, it would be helpful. Perhaps there is more of Br\AmEn distinction?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, funny you should mention that.  I originally had a couple of paragraphs explaining that "in" and "on" can flip context depending on whether contextually you do something "in" or "on" the location (my example used ships, specifically an aircraft carrier).  I chose to delete that portion because it wasn't specifically an issue with the OP's question.

Comment: I am still confused. So "peeing on the street" meaning the consequence of peeing, we can say "He peed in the street, which lead him to pee on the street"?

Comment: @frbsfok, yes, you could say that.  It's verbose, but completely correct.  It makes sense when you think of it this way, "He peed in the street, but peed on a manhole cover."  Manhole covers can occur in places other than a street, so the sentence is very clear about both what happened and where it happened.  Note that a concise way of expressing that example sentence is, "he peed in the street, on a manhole cover."  Using your example, "he peed in the street, on the street."  Meaning he didn't pee on a car, or a pedestrian, or the painted stripes, just generally on the surface of the street.

Comment: JBH - "he peed in the street, on the street." - the repetition of 'street' would be avoided by native speakers. If the intended message is that he peed _in a public place_ then the precise destination of the urine is irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, you're nitpicking in a way that doesn't help the OP solve his/her problem.  Of course the repetition is undesirable.  But when the question is "how do I read the notes?" you don't end the lesson with "and now we'll sing opera."